# React + SVGs: Fill and stroke are not coloring properly

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create an outlined button with an icon in it

Here's the shortened version of my CSS for styling the SVG:

```
const outlinedStyles = css`
    svg {
      path {
        fill: #22222d;
        stroke: #22222d;
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

And the component in case you're curious

```
const Button = ({
  disabled,
  full_width,
  variant,
  size,
  start_icon,
  end_icon,
  children,
  onClick,
}) => (
  <Container
    onClick={onClick}
    disabled={disabled}
    size={size}
    full_width={full_width}
    variant={variant}
  >
    {start_icon && (
      <StartIconContainer variant={variant}>{start_icon}</StartIconContainer>
    )}
    <ButtonText>{children}</ButtonText>
    {end_icon && (
      <EndIconContainer variant={variant}>{end_icon}</EndIconContainer>
    )}
  </Container>
);
```

And the storybook story:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from './Button';
import { ReactComponent as HeartIcon } from '../icons/heart.svg';

import { BUTTON_SIZES, BUTTON_VARIANTS } from '../constants/properties';

export default {
  title: 'forms/Button',
  component: Button,
  args: {
    children: 'Hello world',
  },
  argTypes: {
    onClick: { action: 'clicked' },
    disabled: {
      type: 'boolean',
    },
    full_width: {
      type: 'boolean',
    },
    variant: {
      type: 'select',
      options: Object.values(BUTTON_VARIANTS),
    },
    size: {
      type: 'select',
      options: Object.values(BUTTON_SIZES),
    },
  },
};

const Template = (args) => <Button {...args} />;

...

export const StartIcon = Template.bind({});
StartIcon.args = {
  start_icon: <HeartIcon />,
};

...
```

When I load the button in storybook, instead of black the icon is grey.

[image]

[Here's a link to the storybook for the button](https://twicapp-ui-git-edmund-button-v2-twic.vercel.app/?path=/story/forms-button--start-icon&args=variant:outlined) . Click "outlined" under the variant control on the bottom. Also you open up `SvgIcon` doc and change the fill and stroke, you will see the same issue.

Is this a code issue? Or an issue with the SVGs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the mask. You can replace it with the filled version:

```
<mask id="heart_svg__a" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20">
<path d="M0 0H20V20H0V0Z" fill="white"/>
</mask>
```

The entire correct SVG looks like this:

```
<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<mask id="heart_svg__a" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20">
<path d="M0 0H20V20H0V0Z" fill="white"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#heart_svg__a)">
<path d="M10.014 18C10.014 18 5.407 13.992 2.116 10.652C0.8 9.316 0.236 6.032 2.775 3.972C6.065 1.3 10.014 5.976 10.014 5.976C10.014 5.976 13.962 1.3 17.253 3.972C19.716 5.972 19.227 9.316 17.911 10.652C14.635 13.977 10.014 18 10.014 18Z" fill="#22222D" stroke="#22222D" stroke-width="1.3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi! The mask looks like it's just coming from the SVG itself (I didn't manually add that into the component). Does that mean I need to directly edit the SVGs in Figma and re-export them?

Comment: Yes exactly. The mask is set inside the SVG.
You can also completely remove the mask if you don't need it.

I updated my answer with the entire correct SVG file.